# Amazon EC2 some of the Bower_componente shows 404

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404, bower

I created an instance of Amazon EC2 redhat 7.x, installed node and etc e made upload of my source to it.

After i installed everything with npm install and bower install, when I run it with node server.js and access that on the browser (port 3000) it wont find some of the bower components.

I checked and the files exists and its awful that some components it finds without any problem, just two components is returning 404 (ngToast and ngStorage).

Ex:

Its working great:
http://54.207.52.252:3000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

But this always gives me 404, and the file exists: 
http://54.207.52.252:3000/bower_components/ngtoast/dist/ngToast.min.css

Even tried to tell expressJS to serve bower_components directly but with no success.

Anyone knows what else could be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error of case sensitive. ngtoast should be ngToast. It happened only in redhat